# Selecting ID with a certain entry DB2

Tags: sql, db2, case

I was trying to figure this out for a while, and I am definitely lacking experience with DB2, it looks like it should be an easy task to do but still could not think of a way to do that.

As an example I have a table:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |LEVEL |
+------+------+
|1     |L     |
+------+------+
|1     |R     |
+------+------+
|2     |T     |
+------+------+
|1     |T     |
+------+------+
|2     |R     |
+------+------+
```

I am trying to select one ID entry, but the requirement that the entry with level L should be selected first if it exists, then T and then R. It should look like this:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |LEVEL |
+------+------+
|1     |L     |
+------+------+
|2     |T     |
+------+------+
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I tried to concat results first, resulting in table like this:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |LEVEL |
+------+------+
|1     |L,R,T |
+------+------+
|2     |T,R   |
+------+------+
```

And then using CASE with Like, but that didn't work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by case level when 'L' then 1 when 'T' then 2 when 'R' then 3 else 4 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

However, sometimes I like a conditional aggregation approach in this case:

```
select id,
       coalesce(max(case when level = 'L' then level end),
                max(case when level = 'T' then level end),
                max(level)
               ) as level
from t
group by id;
```